# I am trying to export data from different tables. I have pulled same headers from the tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export data from different tables. I have pulled same headers from the tables.

select locationid, qty from a,
select locationid, qty from b,
select locationid, qty from c

Ideally i would like a query to see my data as
 locationid qtyA qtyB qtyc

Could someone help me with SQL Query?

Comment: Try using `join`.  `select locationid, qtyA, qtyB,qtyC from a  join b  on a.locationid=b.locationid join c on c.locationid=b.locationid;`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following queries?

First in ANSI-89:

```
SELECT 
a.locationid as locationIdA, a.qty as qtryA,
b.locationid as locationIdB, b.qty as qtryB,
c.locationid as locationIdC, c.qty as qtryC
FROM
a, b, c
```

In case you need to filter by locationId (joined):

```
SELECT 
a.locationid as locationIdA, a.qty as qtryA,
b.locationid as locationIdB, b.qty as qtryB,
c.locationid as locationIdC, c.qty as qtryC
FROM
a, b, c
WHERE
a.locationid=b.locationid 
AND
b.locationid=c.locationid
```

Also you could try with ANSI-92:

```
SELECT 
a.locationid as locationIdA, a.qty as qtryA,
b.locationid as locationIdB, b.qty as qtryB,
c.locationid as locationIdC, c.qty as qtryC
FROM
a
INNER JOIN b
ON
a.locationid=b.locationid 
INNER JOIN c
ON
a.locationid=c.locationid
```